# How to use a SQL Cross Apply and a MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, merge

Is there a way to use a `Cross Apply` with a `MERGE` statement? I'm new to `Cross Apply` and still trying to figure all of it's tricks out. Here's a mock demonstration of my INSERT and UPDATE that I'm doing on a cell that contains XML nodes:

```
UPDATE NewTable 
SET
    NewTable.ID = ID,
    NewTable.Title =  Parent.Elm.value('(Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    NewTable.[Description] = Parent.Elm.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    NewTable.ChildTitle = Child.Elm.value('(ChildTitle)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    NewTable.StartDate = Child.Elm.value('(StartDate)[1]', 'DATETIME'), 
    NewTable.EndDate = Child.Elm.value('(EndDate)[1]', 'DATETIME')

FROM OldTable
           cross apply
      xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') xp(parent)
           cross apply
      xp.parent.nodes('ChildElement') xc(child)
WHERE OldTable.ID = NewTable.ID

INSERT INTO NewTable(ID, Title, [Description], ChildTitle, StartDate, EndDate )
SELECT

    Parent.Elm.value('(Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Title',
    Parent.Elm.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Description',
    Child.Elm.value('(ChildTitle)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'ChildTitle',
    Child.Elm.value('(StartDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 'StartDate',
    Child.Elm.value('(EndDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 'EndDate'

FROM OldTable
           cross apply
      xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') Parent(Elm)
           cross apply
      Parent.Elm.nodes('ChildElement') Child(Elm)
```

This is the content from my XML File:

```
<ParentElement>
  <Title>parent1</Title>
  <Description />
  <ChildElement>
    <Title>Child 4</Title>
    <Description />
    <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
  </ChildElement>
  <ChildElement>
    <Title>Child1</Title>
    <Description />
    <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
  </ChildElement>
  <ChildElement>
    <Title>Child6</Title>
    <Description />
    <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
  </ChildElement>
</ParentElement>
```

Where I get stuck on the MERGE statement is where to put the cross apply in the 'USING' section:

```
MERGE INTO NewTable AS NewTable
USING OldTable
    cross apply
         xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') xp(parent)
    cross apply
     xp.parent.nodes('ChildElement') xc(child)
    WHERE OldTable.ID = NewTable.ID AND Child.Elm.value('(ChildTitle)[1]', (100)') = ChildTitle
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the `OldTable` as a `Select` statement in your `Using`.  For example:

```
Merge Into NewTable As Target
Using
(   
    Select      Fields
    From        OldTable
    Cross Apply xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') xp(parent)
    Cross Apply xp.parent.nodes('ChildElement') xc(child)
    Where       Child.Elm.value('(ChildTitle)[1]', (100)) = ChildTitle
) As Source On Source.ID = Target.ID
```

The XML bit seems weird to me, but I really don't know as much about XML in SQL as I should.  However, this should point you in the right direction.

All that you would need to add to the `Merge` statement are what you're doing `When Matched` or `When Not Matched`.

Using the fields in your original query, it would look like this:

```
Merge Into NewTable As Target
Using
(   
    Select      ID,
                Parent.Elm.value('(Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)')          [Title],
                Parent.Elm.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(100)')    [Description],
                Child.Elm.value('(ChildTitle)[1]', 'varchar(100)')      [ChildTitle],
                Child.Elm.value('(StartDate)[1]', 'DATETIME')           [StartDate], 
                Child.Elm.value('(EndDate)[1]', 'DATETIME')             [EndDate]
    From        OldTable
    Cross Apply xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') xp(parent)
    Cross Apply xp.parent.nodes('ChildElement') xc(child)
) As Source On Source.ID = Target.ID And Source.ChildTitle = Target.ChildTitle
When Matched Then
    Update
    Set     Title       = Source.Title,
            Description = Source.Description,
            StartDate   = Source.StartDate,
            EndDate     = Source.EndDate
When Not Matched Then
    Insert  (ID, Title, Description, ChildTitle, StartDate, EndDate)
    Values  (Source.ID, Source.Title, Source.Description, Source.ChildTitle, Source.StartDate, Source.EndDate)
;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try! I appreciate your input!

Comment: Siyual! You are awesome! It worked! Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate you taking the time to write out what it should look like with the various steps! I am marking this as the correct answer! I'd like to give you a few thumbs up as well, but I don't have enough reputation to do so! Thanks again! You made my Friday! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain the syntax is correct on the cross apply? I think it should be written as:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT FieldName = xmlFieldData.nodes('/ParentElement') xp(parent)) p
```

I have never used cross apply with merge or XML like that before but I would wonder if this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for offering your help Kyle, I thought my syntax was correct because it worked. But I could be wrong - like I said, I'm new to merges and cross apply.  

Is this correction you're offering suppose to go in the Merge? What does the FieldName represent?

Comment: Well you taught me something there, I didn't know you could use that syntax.

Comment: I wouldn't quote me on any of this Kyle - I could be wrong! I am very new to this and get myself confused easily! This is a mock demo of what I'm working on. I cannot share the actual code because of privacy. So what you think looks weird, might be a mistake. I'm sorry to be so confusing!